# Change post-name when inserting new Post if Specific Category is selected in WP

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, urls

I want to hook a function for first time when new post is being inserted in WP.

when Poetry category is selected I want to change **post-name** with random 7 numeric numbers like

**/poetry/2837410/**

which function should I call that triger only once when new post is posting

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`wp_insert_post_data`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/) filter, and check the `post_category` array for your category ID. (If `$update` is `false`, you'll know it's a new post being added, not an existing post being edited.)

Something like this should work.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse414180_maybe_change_slug', 10, 4 );
/**
 * Changes the slug on posts in the Poetry category.
 *
 * @param  array $data    The sanitized, slashed, processed post data.
 * @param  array $postarr The sanitized, slashed post data.
 * @param  array $unclean The slashed post data. Unsanitized. We won't use this.
 * @param  bool  $update  Is this a post update?
 * @return array          The (possibly filtered) post data.
 */
function wpse414180_maybe_change_slug( $data, $postarr, $unclean, $update ) {
    if ( $update ) {
        // This is an existing post being updated; return.
        return $data;
    }
    $poetry_category = get_category_by_slug( 'poetry' );
    if ( empty( $poetry_category ) ) {
        // No poetry category, so we return early.
        return $data;
    }
    if ( in_array( $poetry_category->term_id, $postarr['post_category'] ) ) {
        // Random 7-digit number. Note: no collision checking.
        $data['post_name'] = rand( 1000000, 9999999);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

### Note

This code is **untested** and meant as a starting point, not necessarily a finished product; try it out on a test site first.

I haven't added anything to make sure a given slug (ie, `post_name`) isn't already in use.

### References

- [`wp_insert_post_data`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/)
- [`get_category_by_slug()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_by_slug/)
- [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array)
- [`rand()`](https://www.php.net/rand)